# Finding small-length RSA private key

Tags: cryptography, encryption

I was wondering if there is an algorithm to derive $p$ and $q$ or is it simply trial and error?

> Consider the following RSA crypto-system with public key $(437,13)$. Since the numbers are so small, it is possible to break the crypto-system and determine the private key. What is the value of the two primes $p,\,q$ with $n=p\times q$ used in the key generation.
>
> Hint: You may ignore the value $13$ in your computations.

The answer is $23$ and $19$ but I was wondering if there is an algorithm for it?

Thanks!

Comment: I rolled back the edit to the question. It's crucial to the answer that the numbers are small, and questions shouldn't be edited in a way that makes answers invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Of course there’s an algorithm for it. Trial division is an algorithm, a very straightforward one.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the odd target number by 3, 5, 7, and 11 to see if they are factors.

Then beginning with the number 11, increment with the values of 2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,2,4,2,4,8,6,4,6,2,4,6,2,6,6,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,2,10,2,10 as continuing and repeating .

Finally, divide the odd target number by each incremented number to see if one of them is a factor. Continue dividing by the incremented numbers up to the square root of the target number if no factors are previously found.

One note, I found the increments that produce a sequence of odd numbers with multiples of 3, 5, and 7 removed just by working logically with a sequence of odd numbers. However, the increments can also be determined using Wheel Factorization formulas. But I think it is faster to increment with 48 hard-coded array values than to compute.

Comment: You should probably explain that your sequence consists of the *gaps* between the small primes. You might have well started it with an extra 2,2,4.

Comment: The increments produce a sequence of odd numbers with multiples of 3, 5, and 7 removed. The sequence does contain all the forward prime numbers but also contains composite numbers. Use of the number sequence in factoring reduces the number of required divisions and is a major increase in performance

Comment: That would be a good thing to explain in your answer, though I think you can assume that $n$ is the product of two primes.

Comment: The sequence of odd numbers with multiples of 3, 5, and 7 removed, is very little computational overhead in exchange for the increase in performance. Developing all prime numbers for the factoring operation would be much more computational overhead.

Comment: You can explain all of this in your answer.

Comment: I wouldn't mind adding explanation to the algorithm but the comment section has already been used. But furthermore, I can say that 17 digit numbers are small numbers in cryptography and the algorithm can reasonably perform on a 17 digit number.

Comment: Your answer as it stands is incomplete. One should not have to read the comments in order to understand your answer.